# Google Maps Esconder Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Estou com um problema.
Não estou conseguindo deletar os Markers do Google Maps.
A intenção é quando clicar em um Radio Button, marque um lugar, e remova os outros.

Quando eu clico em um Radio Button, ele funciona, e marca um ponto no mapa.
Porem quando eu clico em outro Radio, ele não apaga os pontos ja marcados

HTML:

```
<div id="mapa" class="hidden-xs"></div>

<div id="mapa-lugares">
    <input type="radio" name="lugar" value="lugar1">lugar 1</input>
    <input type="radio" name="lugar" value="lugar2">lugar 2</input>    
</div>
```

Java Script:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MINHA_KEY&amp;sensor=false"></script>

<script>
var map; 
var markers = [];

var lat2 = "-19.212355602107472";
var lng2 = "-44.20234468749999";


$("input[name = 'lugar']").click(function(){

    if($('input:radio[name = lugar]:checked').val() == "lugar1"){
     marcarPonto(lat2 , lng2);
        alert($('input:radio[name = lugar]:checked').val());

    }

     if($('input:radio[name = lugar]:checked').val() == "lugar2"){
     deleteMarkers();       
        alert($('input:radio[name = lugar]:checked').val());

    }
});



function initialize(){
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-18.8800397, -47.05878999999999);   
    var options = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };  
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), options);
}

function marcarPonto(lat , lng){    
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat , lng),
        title: "Meu ponto personalizado! :-D"
        //icon: 'img/marcador.png'
    });
    marker.setMap(map); 

}

function deleteMarkers() {
    clearMarkers();
    markers = [];
}

initialize();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não definiu a função '**clearMarkers**'.

```
function clearMarkers() {
    setMapOnAll(null);
}
```

Comment: Fiz isso. Coloquei um alert dentro da função. E quando chamo, o alert aparece, porem o setMapOnAll não funciona.

Comment: Veja se esse exemplo ajuda: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove